# Recursive function not working when matching more than one item

Tags: php, arrays, recursion

An array with the following structure

```
[
  'name' => :string
  'size' => :string|int
]
```

must be **recursively** converted into an object anytime it encounters this structure in iteration.

So, I wrote these functions

```
// Converts an array into the instance of stdclass
function to_entity(array $file){
    $object = new stdclass;

    $object->name = $file['name'];
    $object->size = $file['size'];

    return $object;
}

// Converts required arrays into objects
function recursive_convert_to_object(array $files){
    foreach ($files as $name => $file) {
        // Recursive protection
        if (!is_array($file)) {
            continue;
        }

        foreach ($file as $key => $value) {
            if (is_array($value)) {
                // Recursive call
                $files[$name] = recursive_convert_to_object($files[$name]);
            } else {
                $files[$name] = to_entity($file);
            }
        }
    }

    return $files;
}
```

Now, when providing an input like this:

```
$input = [
    'translation' => [
        1 => [
            'user' => [
                'name' => 'Tom',
                'size' => 2
            ]
        ]
    ]
];
```

And calling it like this, it works as expected (i.e an ecountered item `user` is being converted to `stdclass` via `to_entity()` function:

```
print_r( recursive_convert_to_object($input) );
```

Now here's the problem:

if an input like this gets provded (i.e one item with the key `4 => [...]` is added) it no longer works throwing `E_NOTICE` about undefined indexes both `name` and `size`.

```
$input = [
    'translation' => [
        1 => [
            'user' => [
                'name' => 'Tom',
                'size' => 2
            ]
        ],

        4 => [
            'user' => [
                'name' => 'Tom',
                'size' => 5
            ]
        ],
    ]
];
```

Let me repeat, that the depth of the target array is unknown. So no matter what depth is, it must find and convert an array into the object.

So where's the logical issue inside that recursive function?

Comment: Add a `var_dump($name, $file);` before your `$files[$name] = to_entity($file);` line, that should help you narrow down the problem.

Comment: I think instead of modifying the `$files` array passed into `recursive_convert_to_object()`, you should create a new one to build and then return that.

Comment: Would calling it with `print_r( recursive_convert_to_object($input['translation']) );` do (as it seems to work OK)

Comment: @NigelRen The content of that array is user-generated, therefore relying on a specific key is not a solution. For example, on next request there might not be the key named `translation` and the array might be much deepest on its own (but still having `[name => '', size => ]` somewhere inside it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this is the best method to solve the problem, but as you already have invested some time in it.

The issue is that once you have replaced some of the content in the array, you put an object back in the array. Then when you test if it's an array in

```
if (is_array($value)) {
```

which it isn't so you convert it into an entity, it's trying to convert the object again.

To stop this happening...

```
            if ( !is_object($value))    {
                $files[$name] = to_entity($file);
            }
```